# IOS/Objective C/UIImage: Why is CGSize causing crash?

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgsize

I have the following line in a category designed to crop an image:

```
CGSize mainImageSize = self.size;
```

When I call the category, the app crashes at this point.  The console shows:

```
size    CGSize  (width=142, height=142) 
mainImageSize   CGSize  (width=2.121995791459338E-314, height=2.121995791459338E-314)
```

Similarly, if you hold the cursor over the self.size, it displays 142,142 while if you hold it over mainImageSize it shows 2.212..., 2.212... etc.

While I can guess why self.size might equal 142x142--it is approximately the image size of the view (150x150) in the view controller, I would interpret this line to mean that we are setting a new variable mainImageSize to the construct CGSize, so I have no idea where the 2.12.. is coming from.  As far as I know mainImageSize is not a reserved word although maybe it is.  I have certainly not defined it as a variable.

This category is called with the following line in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method where chosen image is the image selected:

```
UIImage *thumbnail = [chosenImage createThumbnailToFillSize:CGSizeMake(side, side)];
```

Can anyone walk me through what is actually happening here and hopefully suggest a way to do this that does not crash?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: May 13 14:30:07 Ms-MacBook-Air.local idaru[52066]: hello
May 13 14:30:14 Ms-MacBook-Air assertiond[52038]: assertion failed: 13F34 12B411: assertiond + 11523 [3F572A0B-7E12-378D-AFEE-EA491BAF2C36]: 0x1
May 13 14:30:44 --- last message repeated 1 time ---

Answer (score 0):

The:

```
mainImageSize   CGSize  (width=2.121995791459338E-314, height=2.121995791459338E-314)
```

you obtain seems to be sort of FLOAT_MIN value, are you sure that the instance exists? what about the method you use to create the thumb are you sure that is working fine?

Comment: instance of which?  the thumb is defined in line after this one with simply UIImage *thumb;  Am trying to follow this book: https://books.google.com/books?id=68L0dC2Sl8IC&pg=PA227&lpg=PA227&dq=mainImageSize+ios&source=bl&ots=NfntdVPrf9&sig=1LU4B6moXBnp9ZYv6zRmdD4KMxc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TlpTVYmGKPPmsAT9pIGgDQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=mainImageSize%20ios&f=false

Comment: Instance of UIImage, are you sure that exist?, are you sure that inside the operations you aren't doing some weird math such as dividing by zero

Comment: You can see full code if you click on google books link.  There is math but it comes after this line.  Doesn't crash occur at first point where there is issue

Comment: If you want to debug your code and understand what is wrong, you should  provide all the necessary information to help you find the solution to your problem, not the other way around. I hope you understand

Comment: I previously asked a question with the complete code and no one responded possibly because all the code confused things.  Therefore I pared it down to the key line causing the error, to whit, what the odd 2.12 means.  However, no one seems to know the answer to this either.